# How can I communicate in a secure way with my firefox extension

Tags: security, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am working on a webpage that depends on browser extensions to perform certain tasks.

From the webpage I can communicate with the chrome browser using 'externally_connectable' and:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(string extensionId, any message, object options, function responseCallback)
```

The good thing here is that from the point of view of my website I am sure I am communicating with my extension and not with a 'reverse engineered' version of my extension.

In firefox extensions however there is no support for externally_connectable and I have to use events or window.postmessage:

```
const event = new CustomEvent('msg-for-content-script');
document.querySelector('body').dispatchEvent(event);
```

This works ok, but the problem is that when somebody manages to reverse engineer my extension I am not able to check whether the extension I am communicating with is really my extension.

Is there anybody who can give advice on how to make sure that I am communicating with the right extension?

Comment: There's no secure workaround. Consider voicing your concerns in https://bugzil.la/1319168

Comment: Thanks, i added this to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1319168